# Target CSS to specific eDirectory page

Tags: html, css

I want to make the major event image on the left height larger, without affecting other pages.

https://islandeguide.com/event/

I Noticed this page has this that makes it unique

```
h2 class="theme-title" data-trans="Featured Events">Featured Events/h2
```

So I thought I may be able to do something like

```
page.themetitle[Featured Events] .col-sm-5 > .theme-box.theme-box-vertical > .theme-box-content img{
height: 350px;
}
```

I made this part up `page.themetitle[Featured Events]` so I knew it would not work.

Does anyone know if I can put something there that would work?

**Note:**

I can add CSS to custom CSS document, but that is all! I do not have access to change the HTML/PHP, also I can not add Javascript.

This website was designed in a way that makes it very difficult to target elements without changing others on different pages, as they share Classes everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
h2[data-trans="Featured Events"].theme-title + div.row div.col-sm-5 div.theme-box.theme-box-vertical img {
    height: 350px;
}
```

**Edit:** You can shorten it a little using the child selector:

```
h2[data-trans="Featured Events"].theme-title + .row > .col-sm-5 > .theme-box.theme-box-vertical img {
        height: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Genius, this appears to have worked, thank you so much! One small question, am I able to make this like a media query, so I can stack a whole bunch of CSS just for that page without writing that snippet you made for every element?

Comment: This is difficult, because you only get the next adjacent sibling `div.row` with the `+` selector. It would be better if you had `theme-title` as class in the `html` or `body` tag to match any element you want...